# Groovy, Grape and HtmlUnit

Tags: groovy, htmlunit

could someone instruct me how to Grape-include HtmlUnit in a Groovy (1.7.5) script so that it actually works? Here's what I'm doing:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.8'),
    @GrabExclude('xml-apis:xml-apis')
])
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*

def client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_2)
def page = client.getPage("http://www.google.pl/")
```

and this exception is being thrown:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ObjectInstantiationException: unable to create HTML parser
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:515)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.<init>(HTMLParser.java:440)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:328)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:304)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:134)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:101)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:447)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:330)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:387)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:372)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at scrap.run(scrap.gsh:9)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:264)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:513)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:170)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run.call(Unknown Source)
at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure16.doCall(Console.groovy:890)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure16.doCall(Console.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:354)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried it with HtmlUnit versions 2.4 and 2.6 and it's still the same. Please help!!!

Comment: OMG!!! maven-ant-tasks jar contains an obsolete version of those classes! When is this Jar nightmare come to an end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the installer version of Groovy one of the files being added to the lib folder (and thus automatically added to the classpath) is **maven-ant-tasks**. This one contains the classes that cause problems.

Solution: either remove this one from the lib folder or use the zipped distro of Groovy that does not contain this library.